# Taylor's remainder in a compact

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, interpolation

My impression is that each function enough regular ($C^\infty$ ) in a compact is equivalent to a polynomial.  Is this true?

Is there a way to prove it? 
The expression of the Taylor's remainder just goes to 0 with the increasing expansion of the series. Is there a way to show that the remainder is actually 0 and independent from $x$?.

Comment: Your impression, if I have understood it correctly, is dead wrong.

Comment: can you show a counter example ?

Comment: @Donbeo: what about the $\exp$ function on $[0,1]$?

Comment: ok I am 99% wrong. Is there a proof of that?

Comment: No matter how many times you differentiate the exponential function, you get the same function back. Differentiate a polynomial enough times, you are left with zero.

Comment: Yes you are right. Can my thesis be true with additional hypothesis ?